# Angular2 Firebase : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2. While trying to get the values from Firebase API , I am getting below Error:

```
OPTIONS https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Failed to load https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data: Response for preflight has 

invalid HTTP status code 405
```

But I am able to post the data to Firebase API Endpoint.

I also tried other solutions provided on this community but it did not help. Below is my code.

**Code:**

```
 getServer(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json') ;
    headers.append('charset','UTF-8');
    headers.append('Accept','application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get('https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data',options)
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                for (const server of data) {
                  server.name = 'FETCHED_' + server.name;
                }
                return data;
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error: Response) => {
              return Observable.throw('Something went wrong');
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: IS firebase app https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data created by you? or is it something given by udemy?

Comment: It is given by udemy.. thats not concern. I am able to post the data but could not use get.
I tried creating my own firebase endpoint and that did not work also.. 
Can you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

There are two [sample functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) provided by the Firebase team that demonstrate the use of CORS:

- [Time server with date formatting](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server)
- [HTTPS endpoint requiring Authentication](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint)

The second sample uses a different way of working with cors than you're currently using.

Also, consider importing like this, as shown in the samples:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add .json to your endpoint. Try hitting https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data.json. It gives 404. You can try hitting the one you created. Please have a look on the plunk I created.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTZ9QXsDWRlvboPh2OEu?p=preview

```
let _url = 'https://irelief-3ff8d.firebaseio.com/bookings.json';
    //https://udemy-ng-http.firebaseio.com/data
     this.http.get(_url, { headers: headers }).subscribe((response)=>{
      alert('response >> '+JSON.stringify(response));
      this.responseData = response;
    },err => alert('status : '+err.status)));
```

You need to replace the url with your own app. Hope this helps.

P.S. I am using angular version 4.4.6 for this example.